# How to search for employee name using internal id? Suitescript 2.0

Tags: javascript, search, netsuite, suitescript

How do I search for an employee's name using their internal Id? I've tried using the getText function on the object to get the sales rep name instead of the internal id, but SS2.0 won't allow that. I've also tried using a search.fieldLookUp function, but that spat out errors for me too.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

define(['N/search'],

function(search) {

    return {
        afterSubmit : function(context){
            //log.debug('hello world');
            var customer = context.newRecord;

            var custId = customer.getValue('entityid');
            var custEmail = customer.getValue('email');
            var salesRep = customer.getValue('salesrep');
```

Comment: It looks like your code snippet is incomplete, could you edit your question to include the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use search lookup to retrieve the employee's name:

```
var employeeNameFieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
    type: search.Type.EMPLOYEE,
    id: employeeInternalId ,
    columns: ["firstname", "middlename", "lastname"]
});

var firstname = employeeNameFieldLookUp.firstname;
var middlename = employeeNameFieldLookUp.middlename;
var lastname = employeeNameFieldLookUp.lastname;

var employeeName = [firstname, middlename, lastname].join(" ");
```